# python pandas df merge on part of multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-science

I am using Python 3 with pandas.

I have two data frames, with multi-index, one's index is made of columns a,b and the other's is made of column a,b,c for the sake of this post lets call the data frames ab and abc accordingly.

I would like to use a left merge with pandas like so

abc.merge(ab, how="left") and use the index to create the merge. off course I need only a,b in the index because c is not in ab, how can I create this merge without dropping levels and without reset_index?

A simple and effective solution that will use the multi index is preferred.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get same results using `join` since it is more index-focused. This is an MVE that I used to teach in an introduction to `pd.MultiIndex`:

```
first_index = [('A', 'a'), ('A', 'b'), ('B', 'a'), ('B', 'b')]
second_index = [('A', 'a', 'c'), ('A', 'b', 'c'), ('B', 'a', 'c'), ('B', 'b', 'c')]
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

ab = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(first_index, 
                                                             names=['A', 'B']), 
                  columns=['col_1'])
abc = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(second_index, 
                                                              names=['A', 'B', 'C']), 
                   columns=['col_2'])
```

```
ab
A   B   col_1
A   a   1
A   b   2
B   a   3
B   b   4
```

```
abc
A   B   C   col_2
A   a   c   1
A   b   c   2
B   a   c   3
B   b   c   4
```

So till now, this is just simple MultiIndex with names, but with using join on those names:

```
abc.join(ab, on=['A', 'B'], how='left')
A   B   C   col_2   col_1
A   a   c   1   1
A   b   c   2   2
B   a   c   3   3
B   b   c   4   4
```

You get the `left` join without an `reset_index`.